# How to get all the tasks of a user in Rally

Tags: rally

As a part of my application I need to display the sum of Estimate, ToDo and Actuals(as done in TeamStatus Tab) for all the tasks owned by users in a given project and workspace. To do this I was planning to retrieve all the tasks owned by each single user in the project and then summing up the particular values of Estimate, ToDo and Actuals. How do I know the people who are involved in the particular project? Is there any way to get all the tasks owned by a user? How should I approach towards this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the following Stackoverflow answer pretty useful - this matches your needs almost to a T:

[Query tasks by team members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8851691/query-tasks-by-team-members)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Unfortunately That code is not working out for me.The documentation for rally App SDK 2.0p4 does not have any information about rallydatasource. If the component(rallydatasource) is not deprecated how should I get it working?I have included the latest version of app sdk 2.0p4

Comment: The example from the previous answer was written in the older AppSDK1. However, the query structure does provide some illustration of the data retrieval you'd need to do in AppSDK2 to accomplish your goal.